# What will be the eigen vector of $A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$Ax = ax$ and $x$ is an eigen vector of $A$ corresponding to the eigen value $a$ . What will be the eigen vector of $A^t$ corresponding to the eigen value $a$.

Can anyone please give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to construct the eigenvector, I suggest a solution using diagonalization. We know that there exists $g\in GL_n$ such that $$
gAg^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 & 0 & 0 &\dots & \dots & 0\\
0 & a & 1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0\\
 &  & \ddots & & & \\
& & & a & & \\
& & & & J_1 & & \\
& & & & & \ddots &\\
& & & & & & J_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$ Here, the first block on the diagonal is the Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$ and $J_i$ are the rest of Jordan blocks.

Observe that $gAg^{-1}e_1 = a e_1$ and so $gx = e_1$. Now, take the transpose. The observation is that if the Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$ has size $k$, then its transpose has $e_k$ as an eigenvector with the eigenvalue $a$. This is because $$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0& \dots &\dots &0 \\
1 & a &0 &\dots & 0 \\
& 1& \ddots & &\\
& & \ddots & & \\
& & & 1 & a  
\end{bmatrix}\cdot e_k = a e_k.
$$ We go back by multiplying $e_k$ with $g^{t}$, i.e. if $y=g^t e_k $, then $A^t y=ay$. This is true since $$
A^t y = A^t g^t e_k = g^{t} (g^{t})^{-1}A^t g^t e_k = g^t (ae_k)=ay.
$$